# Custom Android Dialog orientation change

Tags: java, android, layout, orientation, android-orientation

I have a problem on rotation with custom dialog.

My dialog has separate layouts for portrait and landscape orientations. The launching Activities manage their own changes through onConfigurationChanged.

The problem is that, when rotation occurs with the dialog visible, it retains the layout it was started with. Is there a way to update the dialog's layout without changes to each Activity that may show it?

Comment: Plz post the code in your activity.  This way, the SO commuunity can help you more precisely.  Also, its part of the rules.

Comment: @forgivegod: The 2 short sentences he used give all the context necessary, I think: a Dialog is shown from Activities (plural) that are not recreated on orientation change. What else do you need? Easier than trudging through code that is mostly irrelevant to the core issue, which, the way I see it, is that the Activity is not even supposed to be modified (either there are many, or they belong to someone else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the Activities use onConfigurationChanged in order to change only their layouts while keeping data, tasks, etc. It would seem silly to have each of them update the Dialog when necessary. Makes sense for the Dialog itself to do this - but Dialogs don't have onConfigurationChanged.
Changing your Dialog into a dialog-themed Activity would do what you need.

It's a workaround, not a solution, though, so I hope someone has a better idea.

Comment: I went for the solution with dialog-themed Activity since I could not find anything on how to solve this in a dialog. It works as it should.